# Trouble on shutdowning my laptop

Tags: shutdown

I have a laptop Compaq Presario R4000 and because of the end of support to Windows XP -installed previously on it- I decided finally to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Now I have only this OS on my laptop, but it doesn't shutdown. It closes every apps and goes to the screen with the name of UBUNTU and the little spots below, and continues like this for all the time. I have to push the on/off button for a 5 seconds and shutdown my laptop like this. I tried to change grub, and to change modules, and to try to shutdown from the terminal but it doesn't run.
¿May someone help me, please? Thank you and best regards.

Answer (score 0):

[From Terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal) you can use the poweroff command to perform a soft shutdown, rather than the more destructive hard shutdown you've used by holding down the power button.  Close all of your programs and windows, then run this from Terminal:

```
sudo poweroff now
```

You'll need to enter your password, and should see the machine softly shutdown.